# JavaScript: How to affect the outside world in a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

My node script imports an XHTML document, and exports it in ebook formats using Calibre's ebook-convert utility. All of that works fine.

Some of my source documents contain MathML markup in addition to other XHTML content. I'm trying to use [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node) along with [mathjax-node-svg2png](https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-svg2png) to replace the MathML with images.

Here's some of my dumb code:

```
let einstein = `
<blockquote class='eqtn'>
  <p>We will now prove the Pythogorian theorem: <mml:math> <mrow> <msup><mi> a </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> <mo> + </mo> <msup><mi> b </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> <mo> = </mo> <msup><mi> c </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> </mrow> </mml:math></p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
  <p><mml:math><mrow><mi>e</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>m</mi><msup><mi>c</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow></mml:math></p>
</blockquote>
  `;

const re = /(\<mml:math.*?\<\/mml:math\>)/g;

var equations = einstein.match(re);

equations.forEach(equation => {

  mjAPI.typeset({
    math: equation,
    format: 'MathML',
    png: true,
    scale: 2
  }, function(data) {

    if(!data.errors) {

      const imageTag = `<img alt="${data.speakText}" src="${data.png}" width="80%"/>`;

      console.log(einstein.replace(equation, imageTag)); // This logs the string
      // twice, each time with a different **single** equation replaced with
      // an image tag.

    }

  });

});
```

I understand why this logs the output twice, and without updating the content, but I'm not sure how to pull it all together to replace **all** the equations with images, given that it's asynchronous. Is there any documentation that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to approach this. You could either do them one at a time, which would be what you would want to do if one change may affect another.

However, since you mentioned async, I'm guessing they won't conflict with one other, so you can do them in parallel.

You can just store your value before you `console.log` it:

```
einstein = einstein.replace(equation, imageTag));
console.log(einstein);
```

`einstein.replace()` returns a new string, so you have to reassign in to the variable.

However, in this case, what I would do is build up a set of replacements, then apply the replacements all at once, once your done building them. In that case, you'll also need to know when you're done. For that, having some kind of counter would be helpful.

```
let einstein = `
<blockquote class='eqtn'>
  <p>We will now prove the Pythogorian theorem: <mml:math> <mrow> <msup><mi> a </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> <mo> + </mo> <msup><mi> b </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> <mo> = </mo> <msup><mi> c </mi><mn>2</mn></msup> </mrow> </mml:math></p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
  <p><mml:math><mrow><mi>e</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>m</mi><msup><mi>c</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow></mml:math></p>
</blockquote>
  `;

const re = /(\<mml:math.*?\<\/mml:math\>)/g;

var equations = einstein.match(re);

var equationsDone = 0;
var replacements = {};
equations.forEach(equation => {

  mjAPI.typeset({
    math: equation,
    format: 'MathML',
    png: true,
    scale: 2
  }, function(data) {

    if(!data.errors) {

      const imageTag = `<img alt="${data.speakText}" src="${data.png}" width="80%"/>`;

      replacements[equation] = imageTag;
      equationsDone++;

      if (equationsDone === equations.length) {
        applyReplacements();
      }
    }

  });

});

function applyReplacements() {
  for (var equation in replacements) {
    einstein = einstein.replace(equation, replacements[equation]);
  }

  console.log(einstein);
}
```

What this does is each time the callback is called, we stick the replacements in an object we can apply later. We also increment a counter we use to keep track of how many we've processed. When we've processed `equation.length`, we've done them all and we can move to the next step, which is applying them.

To apply them, which just loop through the keys of the object (which are our equations) and do the replace. From there, you'd want to pick up `einstein` and do something else with it.

The reason I would do it this way is it gives me more control when it's time to do the replacements and I can do one action at a time. This extra control may be overkill in your use-case, but it can be useful. It'd also allow you to not modify your original string, or to build a new string and pass it to a callback instead.